# Assigning player in an interactive game

Tags: python, list

I am making a solution to a simple game where you can choose the amount of players with maximum 5 players and minimum 2.  Each player is idenitied by their first and last name.

```
max_players = int(input(" Insert the number of players there are there? : "))
while len(players_list) < max_players:
    player1 = input(" What is your first and last name? : ")
    players_list.append(players)
    print("players so far : ")
    player2 = input ("What is your first and last name? :")
    players_list.append(players)
    print("players so far : ")
    print(players_lists)
```

The code works partially. The problem is that although I mentioned the maximum amount of players you can still unse a number higher than 5. Also, when I insert the first name of the player, it shows that the "players" are not defined?
The exepcted output is

```
Hello how many players are in the game?

insert number between 2 and 5

Please insert your name
```

Then the same commad for the other players.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, when I insert the first name of the player, it shows that the "players" are not defined

You try to append `players`, which indeed does not exist before you call it, to `players_list`, which also does not exist. You need to define these two first.

For the number of players limit, you can add a simple check, whether `max_players` is between 2 and 5.

```
max_players = int(input(" Insert the number of players there are ? : "))
while (max_players <2) or (max_players > 5) :
    max_players = int(input(" Number of players must be between 2 and 5. Number of players ? "))

players_list = []
while len(players_list) < max_players:
    player1 = input(" What is your first and last name? : ")
    players_list.append(player1)
    print("players so far : ")
    print(players_list)
```